# CodeSignal: initial method calls 2nd method multiple times with only 1 call?

Tags: c#

I pulled someone's answer to "reverseInParentheses" just to see other ways to solve it and noticed that they have their initial method that calls another method. Nothing new there. But it calls it several times without, from what I can see, another call.

It seems to run the exact amount of occurrences of words in parentheses, so once for "(bar)" twice for "foo(bar)baz(blim)".

I am just really curious why it runs several times without another call? Is this just how Code Signal works? or is this a Main method feature that I am not aware of? Again, I code mostly in Unity where main just isn't a thing so I may just be missing something silly.

```
string reverseInParentheses(string s)
{
    return reverse(s);
}

string reverse(string s)
{
    var l = s.LastIndexOf('(');
    if (l == -1)
        return s;
    var r = s.IndexOf(')', l);
    var arr = s.Substring(l + 1, r - l - 1).ToCharArray();
    Array.Reverse(arr);
    return reverse(s.Substring(0, l) + new string(arr) + s.Substring(r + 1));
}
```

Comment: This technique is called recursion.

Comment: Note that `reverse` calls itself on the last line.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you so much! I knew it was something simple I was missing...